# Sveltekit creates links with placeholders - how to handle them for Google Crawler?

Tags: sveltekit

So I noticed that the Google Crawler finds the placeholder links in SvelteKit that I use to create dynamic links for content pages.
An example would be this blog link: `https://example.com/blog/[slug]`

All links that are on the website itself link to URLs/pages that have the [slug] replaced with the actual slug but Google still finds these links including the placeholder and returns them in the Search Console as 5XX errors.

So my questions are the following:

- Is there a way to prevent Google from finding those links or is this expected?
- If this is expected: How would I set a robots.txt rule that prevents all pages (in all subfolders) that have a "[" and a "]" in them to be crawled by Google?

As I do not want to test this on the live page, I would like to get some confirmation first because I do not want Google to deindex all pages.
I was thinking about a rule like this:

`Disallow: /*[*]*`

but I have no idea if this would work.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

**Edit:** Turns out there is an official Google robots.txt testing tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool
I checked my proposed solution above and it seems to work so I will implement that now.

Would still be interesting to know if this should happen or if there is a way to prevent this within SvelteKit.

Comment: I must confess, I do not understand why these links show up in your content in the first place. The reason they get hit by the crawler is because they are somehow published as is, and that's not right. Do you have a code snippet to share showing how you are using these links, e.g. the `/blog/[slug]` path you mention in your question?

Comment: You are right and it's 100% my approach of running the site as Google also finds "/node_modules" links. It's probably because I don't build the site but simply run "npm run dev" via PM2 behind a nginx reverse proxy. That is probably the reason, right? At some point I read it should be fine to do it that way but I guess it's not and I should find the correct approach.

Comment: Yeah, `/node_modules` shouldn't even be *accessible* via http, never mind get crawled, even when running in dev mode. I am wondering if perhaps in your configuration  you have defined your project root as the base of your static assets, thus serving your entire project files as static assets? This could come from a faulty `svelte.config.js` and/or `vite.config.js` config.

Comment: I left those files basically unmodified. But the "/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/start.js" is actually accessible via http in my case. Well, I will take a look at deploying the application in production instead of in development and check if that fixes it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Another place to look at might be your nginx configuration if for some reason you set nginx to serve your project directory as a static site in addition to setting up your reverse proxy? Just some suggestions ;) Good luck!